# MySQL Function keeps on returning blank page

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please make sure that I'm doing this correctly?

I'm not the best at functions.

```
function checkMaintenance {
    $db = doDB();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Maintenance WHERE Enabled = 1";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $msg = "";
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 1) {
      while ($rows = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $msg = "<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Ruff oh!</strong> '".$rows['Message']."' ?></div>";
        return $msg;
      }
    } else {
      $msg = "";
      return $msg;
    }
    return $msg;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: how many record are there to fetch ?

Comment: What is the value of `$stmt->num_rows`?

Comment: When I alter my code to the answers, It only returns a blank page.

Comment: I'm calling the function in my index.php as.
`<?php checkMaintenance(); ?>`

Comment: can you post the value for $stmt and $stmt->num_rows ?

Comment: Please check my posted answer, Hope this is your solution

Comment: Okay it stopped returning data now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess function should look like this:

```
function checkMaintenance() {
    $db = doDB();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Maintenance WHERE Enabled = 1";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $msg = "";
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($rows = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><strong>Ruff oh!</strong>" . $rows['Message'] . "</div>";
        return $msg;
      }
    }
    return $msg;
  }
```

and call it

`<?= checkMaintenance() ?>` or `<?php echo checkMaintenance() ?>`

Comment: Okay so this solution loads the page but it breaks it and no content is being produced.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I forgot to add the () in the function. You are awesome.

Comment: :D Sometimes it just happens :D

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line :

```
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 1) {
```

With this:

```
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
```

also  wrong syntax

```
 $msg = "..............  .$rows['Message']."' ?></div>";
```

replace with

```
 $msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Ruff oh!</strong>' . $rows['Message']. '</div>';
```

Comment: Still returning a blank page.

Comment: you have closed the php scope by using ?> in $msg statement i think.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below points:

1) First check `$stmt` returns data or not.

2) Replace `if ($stmt->num_rows > 1) {` with `if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {`.

3) Replace

```
$msg = "<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Ruff oh!</strong> '".$rows['Message']."' ?></div>";
```

with

```
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><strong>Ruff oh!</strong> ".$rows['Message']."</div>";
```

4) Call the function like `<?php echo checkMaintenance() ?>`.

Comment: Fixed `$msg`, $stmt does return data.

Comment: @brownzilla I added one more step check all 3 steps.

Comment: I saw and I did that

Comment: @brownzilla Ok, so what is the problem now?

Comment: Whenever I try and refresh my page with `<?php checkMaintenance(); ?>` keeps on returning a blank page.

Comment: @brownzilla From where you call `checkMaintenance()`?

Comment: @brownzilla Have you check the mysql connection is established successfully or not? Have you check your query is correct and it is returning data?

Comment: @brownzilla Have you tried to call a function like `<?php echo checkMaintenance() ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

You need two corrections:

Change:

```
$msg = "<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Ruff oh!</strong> '".$rows['Message']."' ?></div>";
```

To:

```
$msg = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Ruff oh!</strong>' . $rows['Message']. '</div>';
```

You are mixing up double quotes here, causing parse errors. You can use single and double quotes interchangeably, but, they should not be mixed up.

They should be closed properly.

And

```
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 1) {
```

To

```
 if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
```

You are checking if result set contains at least 2 rows `(> 1)`, which is 
incorrect, sometimes, if you have one row, it will not consider it showing wrong results.

So, check if result set has atleast one row. `(> 0)`

Comment: I've done this, it hasn't fixed anything. Still getting a blank page.

Comment: I have changed the alert message statement, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkMaintenance {
    $db = doDB();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Maintenance WHERE Enabled = 1";
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $msg = "";
    //If result set having atleast single records...
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
      //Loop until records exists...
      while ($rows = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><strong>Ruff oh!</strong> " . $rows['Message'] . " ?></div>";
        return $msg;//Return HTML structure...
      }
    } else {
      $msg = "";
      return $msg;//return blank...
    }
  }
 ?>
```

I make some fixing stuff which is require. This should return *HTML* structure if *MySql* result set having atleast single record.

Hope this help you.!

Comment: Nope still returning a blank page onrefresh with <?php checkMaintenance(); ?>

Comment: You need to print the return output from `checkMaintenance`. Viz.  <?php print checkMaintenance(); ?>